# sql-python sorting

Tags: sql

I have the following question: List the top 5 Community Areas by average College Enrollment.

I have created the following code and I want to use DESC to show the top 5 community areas. MY code as it is does not do the trick. I do not know where to put DESC.

```
SELECT COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, COLLEGE_ENROLLMENT, AVG(COLLEGE_ENROLLMENT) 
from CHICAGO_SCHOOLS1 
group by COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, COLLEGE_ENROLLMENT 
LIMIT 5
```

Any ideas? Can you also comment is my code is correct in relation to the question above?

Thanks
Ilias

Comment: `DESC` is an option for the `ORDER BY` keyword, which you don't have.  Also, what does this have to do with python?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the order by statement:

```
SELECT COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, COLLEGE_ENROLLMENT, AVG(COLLEGE_ENROLLMENT)
    FROM CHICAGO_SCHOOLS1
    GROUP BY 1, 2
    ORDER BY 3 DESC
    LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thank you. Any help on this one? [Without using an explicit JOIN operator] Find the Per Capita Income of the Community Area which has a school Safety Score of 1 `%sql select COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, PER_CAPITA_INCOME from CENSUS_DATA where COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME in (select SAFETY_SCORE from CHICAGO_SCHOOLS1 where SAFETY_SCORE = 11)`. Census_data has per_capita_income and community_area_name in it while Chicago_schools1 has safety_score and  community_area_name. @aws_apprentice

Comment: i’m not doing your HW for you, and that is a separate question, if this worked for you, accept it as the solution